# PHP get client URL when be accessed in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, client

I have following code:

```
<script src="http://www.indosense.net/js-iklan.php?kode_zona=7268" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

I put above code in my script website http://www.ridwan.com/index.php

How to get www.ridwan.com in js-iklan.php when I access www.ridwan.com ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript code `location.hostname`. it returns the site url which you see in the browser. Note that this property available in the client side.
To access it from server side this info will be available in http header.